# How can I update json column with a correct data type with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-json

I have MySQL 5.7 and a query with PDO:

```
    $data['id'] = 1;
    $data['key'] = 'new_field';
    $data['value'] = 1;
            
    $query= "
        UPDATE `table`
        SET `data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`data`, JSON_OBJECT(:key, :value))
        WHERE `id` = :id
    ";
    ...
    prepare($query);
    execute($data);
```

But after it I'm having:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"old_field": 2, "new_field": "1"} |

Why does my new value have a string type?
Expected table:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"old_field": 2, "new_field": 1} |

I have success without using PDO(`JSON_OBJECT('new_field', 1)`), but I have a string type with using placeholders.

Comment: `JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`data`, JSON_OBJECT(:key, :value + 0))`

Comment: Please show us the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an array to `PDOStatement::execute()` method, all the values will be cast to string. If you want PDO to keep them as integers you must bound them using `bindValue()` and provide the type hint marking it as an integer.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('key', 'new_field');
$stmt->bindValue('value', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Alternatively, you can cast the value to an integer in SQL, either by adding a zero to it or by using `CAST(:value AS SIGNED)`.